# Am I using conditional entropy formula correctly?

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I want to use the formula for a measure of complexity of a system:
$$C(X) = H(X) - \sum_{x \in X}{H(x\mid X-x)}$$
where $x$ is a subpart of the system $X,$ and $H(X)$ is shannon entropy.

Then I have used the conditional entropy formula [1] to alter the summation to:

$$\sum_{x \in X}{H(X-x,x) - H(X-x)}$$

my question is weather it is correct to calculate the $H(X-x,x)$ simply as $H(X)$ ?
hopefully this is the right place to ask this

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy

Comment: Could you clarify how to interpret your notation--what kind of mathematical objects are $X$ and $x$? And, what does $X-x$ refer to?

Comment: I've tried to keep it generic. But specifically in this case the system is a network of nodes. X refers to the state of the network, x is the state of one particular node in the network and X-x is the state of all nodes in the network except for x. In order to estimate the probability function needed to calculate H(X) I observe the state of the network(the state of all nodes) over time

Comment: I don't understand your Notation $X-x$: what do you mean with it?